# Laravel 5 pagination with trailing slash redirect to 301

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, pagination, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 and notice that the pagination is adding a trailing slash before the `?page=#` and with that, it always redirect to a 301 page.

`http://example.com/news/articles/?page=2` will do a 301 redirect to `http://example.com/news/articles?page=2`

This is causing my pagination using ajax to slow down because it is having 2 responses.

How to make laravel accept `http://example.com/news/articles/?page=2` so it won't make a 301 redirect?

I base it through [this](http://laravel.io/forum/11-13-2014-laravel-5-pagination) site which is using `LengthAwarePaginator`.

Comment: can you show your code that you are using for pagination

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look in your `app/public/.htaccess` file you will see this line:

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

By removing it you will disable trailing slash redirect.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! It is working now. Though I have a question. Should this be removed, are there "side effects"? Like SEO or any? Why was it included in the first place? Im sure there is a reason for this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this in my controller *instead of modifying .htaccess*

```
    $posts= Article::latest()->paginate(4);
    $posts->setPath('');//just add this line after your paginate function
```

or some users might prefer to add this line when they generate links in view

```
$links = str_replace('/?', '?', $posts->render());
```

Answer (score 0):

@shaddys answer is most properly the better solution, but I couldn't use it because of other routes. So I've just done it like this

```
$.ajax({
     url: url.replace('/?','?'),
      ....
});
```

With this you will get working pagination and no redirections.